# create grid column without using fluent api

Tags: vaadin8

I can add column to grid like this

```
jobGrid.addComponentColumn(info -> info.getName())
    .setId(NAME)
    .setCaption("Column Name")
    .setWidth(70);
```

But I want to create a generator that would provide already created columns to the grid. Basically I want something like this

```
jobGrid.addColumn(generateColumn())
```

How to do that?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. The [`Column` constructors are protected](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/a996b95422174ccef1a212a33fd25fa3c7c66fae/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.java#L943) and the `Grid` itself is creating them. Here's a wild thought, tho', depending on what you want to achieve, perhaps you could shift the perspective by using a _"column configurator"_ instead of generator, something along the lines of `configure(grid::addColumn)`...

Comment: @Morfic and did it exactly similar to this - pass `grid` to generator and `addColumn` in there